# Am I required to have my website registered as a business in Canada to collect HST?

Tags: taxes, canada, small-business, hst, sales-tax

Am I required to have my website registered as a business in Canada ON, to be able to sell ads? does the amount of income makes any difference?

The reason I am asking this is I have been told that if I am selling (any goods or services) I should register as a business to collect Harmonized Sales Tax (HST).

Comment: This is not really personal finance, more like business advice. If you ask the same question on startups.stackexchange.com, make sure to include more details - you are basically asking "does advertising work?", which is too broad for any stackexchange site to answer.

Comment: No, that's not what I am asking. I have updated the question, please see above.

Comment: "Should I do X?" is prone to being opinion-based. Is your real question actually "am I required to do X?"?

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I think this sort of question has historically been allowed here - this is not a real business, this is a hobby business or similar, sole proprietorship sort of thing (which has its own entry under [on-topic](http://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: I also think that this question now is reasonable and answerable, thanks to the editing.

Comment: @Joe I agree, after the edits (which make it about HST, and not simply effectiveness of advertising), the question is now answerable.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://money.stackexchange.com/a/64285/13241) and the link for internet business.  You don't sell ads but earn money from hosting or delivering eyeballs to them.  There used to people that actually sold advertising.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I don't think your edit is quite right.  I think they're asking whether they need to (register as a business and collect HST) in order to sell ads, no?  (Not Canadian so perhaps I have a misunderstanding here.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If you run a sole proprietorship, how do you declare the income of the business on your taxes?](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/67/if-you-run-a-sole-proprietorship-how-do-you-declare-the-income-of-the-business)